# Dealing with DPI and ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap

Tags: c++, direct2d

I created this UI framework in Direct2D some time ago to be able to draw/manage my own windows and widgets. I've been using it and updating it according to my needs and it works pretty well. However, now that high resolutions monitors are the new thing, I came across a small problem. Drawing images/icons in the best definition I can.

Since I'm using Direct2D all the draw functions work properly according to the DPIs/scaling of the target machines except of course images that are based in pixels and for that reason are not automatically managed by DirectX.

So, in the beginning I was simply drawing bitmaps as they were in 96 DPI, this meant that if I had an icon 10x10, and I used a function like ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap by specifying a destination rectangle, my image would be scaled up for higher DPIs. This of course would be noticeable and the icon would be blurry.

My first attempt at fixing this was to create my icons 4x bigger than the default DPI of 96. Then, using the same ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap and knowing that these images are 4x bigger, the DrawBitmap would draw the icon scaled down instead of scaled up. This had much better results, Starting from a windows scale of 150% and up it's perfect.

However, scaling down from 4x to 1x, the result is not great, images get somewhat pixelized. Much worse that doing the same in Photoshop.

I also tried using SetTransform before the DrawBitmap so see if the result is better, but it's exactly the same.

So my question is, how are people dealing with this issue. I'm sure I'm not the only one...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get best visual results, you'll need to prepare groups of icons in various resolutions, not just downscaled but specifically designed in lower sizes. Then you'll need to select one of those according to current context.

Regarding DrawBitmap, you could try with different interpolation modes.

As for general solutions that people are using, I don't think there is one. Many applications don't support this properly, or if they do for control layout, embedded bitmap resources are still stretched and look deformed or interpolated and look too blurry.

Comment: This is my next option if I can't find any other solution. I was trying to avoid this because of the extra work and complexity needed do deal with it. This is especially problematic since I usually have multiple "sprites" saved to the same image and crop them when I need them.